# Why are all the VMs in Azure greyed out and unavailable to use? How can I choose a VM?

Tags: azure

[image: All VMs greyed out]

I am just starting to use azure and am following a tutorial.  In the tutorial I am asked to choose a VM to use as a host.  However, when I go to choose the VM, all the options are unavailable (greyed out - see the picture).

What am I doing wrong here?  I have a free beginners pack with £150 credit available, so I can afford the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need to pick another region, vm sizes available to you depend on your subscription type and region. so try using different region (west europe usually works fine). Alternatively you can use:

```
Get-AzVmSize -Location %region_name%
```

to figure out available VM SKU's for you in your region.

ps. you can run powershell cmdlets in the Azure Cloud Shell

Comment: West Europe is slightly better, but no D series VMs are available just now: https://pasteboard.co/J09ynd6.png